# Passing a common variable to a module in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I'd like to create a module in node.js, that includes a couple of functions.
 
I'd also need a common object for all of the functions to use. 
I tried the following syntax, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
module.exports = function(obj) {
    func1: function(...) {

    },
    func2: function(...) {

    }
}
```

Where `obj` is the common object I want the functions to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return your functions object:

```
module.exports = function(obj) {
    return {
        func1: function(...) {

        },
        func2: function(...) {

        }
    };
};
```

Usage:

```
var commonObj = { foo: 'bar' };
var myModule = require('./my-module')(commonObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

`module.exports` is simply the object that is returned by a `require` call.

You could just:

```
var commonObj = require('myObj');

module.exports = {
  func1: function(commonObj) {...},
  func2: function(commonObj) {...}
};
```

Comment: I want to initialize that object from another file (server.js) after I get that object from a different module. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, sorry. You want `server.js` required and run it's `init()` from these functions?

Comment: The object that I need to be available in that module is created in another file. Only after it has been created I want to pass it to the module. Was that clear enough? sorry for that

Comment: So you want to import a file after that file has been created? Sounds like a bad pattern to depend on something not yet existent.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use object syntax within a function. So either get your function to `return` your functions, or just use an object instead and export that. To pass in an argument you'll need something like an `init` function.

```
var obj = {

  init: function (name) {
    this.name = name;
    return this;
  },

  func1: function () {
    console.log('Hallo ' + this.name);
    return this;
  },

  func2: function () {
    console.log('Goodbye ' + this.name);
    return this;
  }

};

module.exports = obj;
```

And then just import it within another file using the `init` method. Note the use of `return this` - this allows your methods to be chained.

```
var variable = require('./getVariable'); // David
var obj = require('./testfile').init(variable);

obj.func1(); // Hallo David
obj.func2(); // Goodbye David
```